# android Media Player stopped working

Tags: android, media-player

Last night, my app was working just fine streaming audio files with the MediaPlayer in my app. I came into work this morning and it wont play any audio file and I havent changed my code at all. here is the error log that it is printing out via LogCat. Also, the audio file still exists and plays fine on anything else.

```
07-07 09:53:39.559: INFO/ActivityManager(92): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x800000 cmp=com.Harvest.org/.MediaPlayerActivity (has extras) }
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.mpeg4' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.h263' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vc1' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.divx' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.encoder.mpeg4' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.video.encoder.h263' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.Qcelp13' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: ERROR/(840): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.evrc' already exists, ignoring this one.
07-07 09:53:39.759: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(840): setDataSource('http://media.libsyn.com/media/harvest/SM100627.mp3')
07-07 09:53:40.769: WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioFlinger server died!
07-07 09:53:40.769: WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioPolicyService server died!
07-07 09:53:40.769: INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
07-07 09:53:40.769: INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.player' died
07-07 09:53:40.769: INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.camera' died
07-07 09:53:40.769: INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.audio_policy' died
07-07 09:53:40.769: WARN/IMediaDeathNotifier(912): media server died
07-07 09:53:40.769: WARN/IMediaDeathNotifier(912): media server died
07-07 09:53:40.769: ERROR/MediaPlayer(912): error (100, 0)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at com.Harvest.org.MediaPlayerService.setDataSource(MediaPlayerService.java:97)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at com.Harvest.org.MediaPlayerActivity$2.onServiceConnected(MediaPlayerActivity.java:292)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1247)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1264)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-07 09:53:40.779: WARN/System.err(912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 09:53:42.279: ERROR/AudioService(92): Media server died.
07-07 09:53:42.279: INFO/ServiceManager(92): Waiting for sevice media.audio_flinger...
07-07 09:53:43.279: INFO/ServiceManager(92): Waiting for sevice media.audio_flinger...
07-07 09:53:44.279: INFO/ServiceManager(92): Waiting for sevice media.audio_flinger...
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(951): audience_a1026 init OK
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/AudioHardwareQSD(951): set_tpa2018d1_parameters() not present
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): libhtc_acoustic.so version 2.0.1.2.
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): open /system/etc/AdieHWCodecSetting.csv success.
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): ADIE table version: PASSION_HTC_20091019
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 0
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 2
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 5
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 7
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 8
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 10
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 51
07-07 09:53:44.439: ERROR/HTC Acoustic(951): Update ADIE table ID 53
07-07 09:53:44.439: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): read_adie_para_from_file success.
07-07 09:53:44.449: DEBUG/HTC Acoustic(951): ioctl ACOUSTIC_UPDATE_ADIE success
07-07 09:53:44.449: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): open /system/etc/AudioBTID.csv success.
07-07 09:53:44.449: INFO/HTC Acoustic(951): BT ID table version: PASSION_HTC_20091105
07-07 09:53:44.449: DEBUG/AudioHardwareQSD(951): mNumBTEndpoints = 25
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Default (tx,rx)=(9,10)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Default Car-kit (tx,rx)=(9,10)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name JKDAP3265 (tx,rx)=(1003,1103)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name JKDAP3264 (tx,rx)=(1004,1104)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name HTC BH M200 (tx,rx)=(1005,1105)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name BH M300 (tx,rx)=(1006,1106)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Jabra BT530 (tx,rx)=(1007,1107)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Jabra BT5010 (tx,rx)=(1008,1108)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Jabra BT3030 (tx,rx)=(1009,1109)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Nokia BH-208 (tx,rx)=(1010,1110)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Nokia BH-703 (tx,rx)=(1011,1111)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Nokia BH-103 (tx,rx)=(1012,1112)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Samsung WEP410 (tx,rx)=(1013,1113)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name 3xxPlantronics (tx,rx)=(1014,1114)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name 6XXPlantronics (tx,rx)=(1015,1115)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name 8XXPlantronics (tx,rx)=(1016,1116)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Motorola H710 (tx,rx)=(1017,1117)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Motorola H12 (tx,rx)=(1018,1118)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Motorola S9 (tx,rx)=(1019,1119)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name HBH-IV840 (tx,rx)=(1020,1120)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name HBH-PV710 (tx,rx)=(1021,1121)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name HBH-DS220 (tx,rx)=(1022,1122)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name HBH-DS980 (tx,rx)=(1023,1123)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name Nexus One Car Dock (tx,rx)=(1024,1124)
07-07 09:53:44.449: ERROR/AudioHardwareQSD(951): BT name END (tx,rx)=(1162429505,1146045279)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being, that the libsyn server was redirecting the urls. which apparently doesnt work in 2.2 froyo. anyway i had to write a HEAD request that followed the redirects and return the final url.